# How do I fix my border to wrap around my text in the center?

Tags: html, css

My border keeps stretching whenever I center the text in the middle. I want the border to be just around the text not around the whole middle area.

Here is my code:

```css
#EnterHouse {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#EnterHouse {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#EnterHouse a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

#EnterHouse a:hover {
  color: red;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="IKWYDLH">Example</div>
  <div id="EnterHouse"><a href="Index.html">Hello World</div></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the text in a `span`. Remove the border from `#EnterHouse` and use padding to give it some extra height. Then just set the border on the `span` element.

```css
#EnterHouse {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#EnterHouse {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#EnterHouse a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

#EnterHouse a:hover {
  color: red;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="IKWYDLH">Example</div>
  <div id="EnterHouse"><a href="Index.html"><span>Hello World</span></a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only use floats and absolutes if you really have to.  For this, change the display to table and add margin: 0 auto

```css
#EnterHouse {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#EnterHouse a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

#EnterHouse a:hover {
  color: red;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="IKWYDLH">Example</div>
  <div id="EnterHouse"><a href="Index.html">Hello World</a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  #EnterHouse {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: x-large;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        overflow: hidden;   
        background-color: black;
        display: inline-block;
    }
#EnterHouse {
float: left;
width: 100%;
  padding:1pc;
  
}
    #EnterHouse a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: orange;
              border: 10px solid yellow;

    
    }
    #EnterHouse a:hover {
        color: red;
      
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.